# Why didn't Khan's abilities transfer into Kirk?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness, captain-kirk, khan-singh

When Kirk dies near the end of *Star Trek Into Darkness*, he comes back to life when Bones administers Khan's blood. Khan is genetically enhanced to be a superior life form, so why didn't Kirk recieve his abilities (such as improved strength) after being injected with his blood?

Comment: Because the blood healed him but didn't transfer DNA

Answer (score 10):

We have no reason to believe that Khan's abilities could be transferred by tissue transplants--and besides, Kirk was never actually injected with Khan's blood. Bones was able to isolate its regenerative activity and develop a serum that produced that same effects:

> MCCOY: Oh, don't be so melodramatic. You were barely dead. it was the transfusion that really took its toll. You were out cold for two weeks.
>
> KIRK: Transfusion?
>
> MCCOY: Your cells were heavily irradiated. We had no choice.
>
> KIRK: Khan?
>
> **MCCOY: Once we caught him, I synthesised a serum from his superblood.** Tell me, are you feeling homicidal? Power mad? Despotic?
>
> KIRK: No more than usual. How'd you catch him?

Even if Kirk had received a direct blood transfusion, it's extremely unlikely that this would have produced any long-term effects. Blood cells do not multiply: they're produced in the bone marrow and die quickly. So Khan's blood would never have stuck around in Kirk's system for long. And in order to give him super strength or intelligence, it would have needed to invade other tissues and rewrite his biology from the ground up, which we never see it do.